# Does IIS6 update the password of the domain account if one is used for the application pool identity?

Tags: domain, iis-6, application-pools

Basically as the question states, if I use a domain account for the application pool, and the domain identity has a requiremet for the password to change every X days, does IIS6 handle the password change automatically or is that always manual process?

I have looked at numerous sites for this answer but I always see the walkthroughs having the user click on 'no expire' and 'do not prompt for new password' (or to that effect). Those two check boxes are not an option for my environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question but I did find the answer, so I'll post it here just to close it off. This is for anyone who might be interested.

The answer is no, IIS does not do user management so using an expiring domain account as the application ID is not the ideal.

The danger here is in a case where the webserver is getting hit constantly, that time period in between changing the password and changing it on the app pool can result in the account getting locked, forcing you to unlock it manually.